# Family of subsets of $[n]$ and intersections

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that for all $A,B,C \in \mathcal{F}$ at most $3$ out of $8$ triples $A\cap B \cap C$, $A \cap B^c \cap C$, $A \cap B \cap C^c$, $A \cap B^c \cap C^c$, $A^c \cap B \cap C$, $A^c \cap B^c \cap C$, $A^c \cap B \cap C^c$ and $A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c$ are non-empty (here $X^c$ is the complement of $X$). Prove that the size $|\mathcal{F}|$ is bounded from above by a constant independent of $n$.

Apart from considering the contrapositive (i.e. prove that if $|\mathcal{F}| > C_0$ then it contains $A,B,C$ with at least four non-empty intersection triples) I do not know what to do. I tried some extreme examples (such as $\mathcal{F}$ to consist of many pairwise disjoint sets) but do not see how to connect them for the general case.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: HINT: The statement is _very_ strong - it said there is a finite max size for $|F|$ even if $n \to \infty$.  Try to construct such $F$ and maximize its size, to see how big you can get $|F|$ to be.  You should find that the max size you can achieve is a very small integer, and that should give you an idea how to prove it.

Comment: @antkam Yep, makes sense that $C_0$ is small, but could you give some more directions on this? As I said, I cannot connect different particular examples :(

Comment: OK another HINT: I suggest playing with $n=2$.  There are only $4$ subsets of $[2]$.  How many of these can you fit into $F$ while satisfying the given property?  Then try $n=3$ and the $8$ subsets of $[3]$.  How many of these can you fit into $F$ while satisfying the given property?

Comment: Ok for $n=2$ the answer is $4$, for $n = 3$ I see that in general I cannot have three pairwise disjoint non-empty subsets whose union is not $[n]$ (or the complements of three such subsets) as these would give 4 intersection triples; so I can take at most $\emptyset$, $\{1,2,3\}$ and at most $2$ from $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ and $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}$ and I think that $\emptyset$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1\}, \{2\}$, $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}$ are fine. Anyway, it was tedious to verify for $n=3$, no general reasons apart from the above observation come up to my mind...

Comment: Probably we can consider some large graph (or hypergraph) and then apply the Ramsey's theorem somehow, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is inspired by Ewan Delanoy’s [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703719/family-of-subsets-of-n-and-non-empty-intersection-triples/3706951#3706951). He bounded size of $\mathcal F$ in terms of [Ramsey numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers), showing that  $|{\mathcal F}| \leq 2+R(2,R(4,4,3))=2+ R(4,4,3)$. The best known bounds for $R(4,4,3)$ are $55\le R(4,4,3)\le 77$, see [R, p. 39]. We shall show that  $|\mathcal F|\le 14$.

Following Ewan Delanoy, given a subset $A$ of $[n]$ we put $A^+=A$, $A^-=A^c$ and let $A^{\pm}$ denotes $A$ or $A^c$. Subsets $A$ and $B$ of $[n]$ are *independent*, if all four intersections $A^{\pm}\cap B^{\pm}$ are nonempty. Assume that $|\mathcal F|\ge 3$.

**Lemma.** The family $\mathcal F$ does not contain independent members.

*Proof*. Suppose to the contrary that $A, B\in\mathcal F$ are independent and $C$ be an arbitrary member of $C$ distinct from $A$ and $B$. For any choice $^*, ^{**}$ of signs in $\pm$, a set $A^*\cap B^{**}$ is nonempty, so at least one of sets $A^*\cap B^{**}\cap C^+$ and $A^*\cap B^{**}\cap C^-$ is non-empty. So the family of sets of the form $A^\pm\cap B^\pm\cap C^\pm$ has at least four non-empty members, a contradiction. $\square$

Let a family $\mathcal F^*$ is obtained from family $\mathcal F\setminus\{\varnothing, [n]\} $ by replacing each member $A$ of $\mathcal F$ with $|A|>n/2$ by $A^c$. Then $|\mathcal F^*|\ge |{\mathcal F}|/2-1$ and $\mathcal F^*$ satisfies the question condition. Since $A^c\cap B^c$ is non-empty for each $A,B\in\mathcal F^*$, Lemma implies that any members of $\mathcal F^*$ are disjoint or one is contained in the other. It follows that any member of $\mathcal F^*$ contains a minimal element and minimal elements of $\mathcal F^*$ are pairwise disjoint. If $\mathcal F^*$ contains four minimal members $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ then sets $A\cap B^c\cap C^c=A$, $A^c\cap B\cap C^c=B$, $A^c\cap B^c\cap C=C$, and $A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c\supset D$ are non-empty, a contradiction. Thus $\mathcal F$ contains at most three minimal elements. Let $A$ be any of them. Suppose to the contrary that there exist distinct elements $B\supset A$  and $C\supset A$ of $\mathcal F^*\setminus \{A\}$. Since $B\cap C\supset A$ is non-empty, it follows that $B\subset C$ or $C\subset B$. Anyway, sets $A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c$,  $A^c\cap B^c\cap C$, $A^c\cap B\cap C$, and $A\cap B\cap C$ are non-empty, a contradiction. Thus each minimal member of $\mathcal F^*$ is contained in at most one other member. Thus $|\mathcal F^*|\le 3\cdot 2=6$, and $|\mathcal F|\le 2(|\mathcal F^*|+1)\le 14$.

*References*

[R] Stanisław P. Radziszowski, *[Small Ramsey numbers](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/DS1/pdf/)*. Dynamic Surveys. Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, revision #15: March 3, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof that $|{\cal F}| \leq 2+R(2,R(4,4,3))$, where $R$ denotes Ramsey numbers.

Let $\cal E$ denote the subets of $[n]$ that are neither empty or full, and ${\cal F}'={\cal F}\cap{\cal E}={\cal F}\setminus \lbrace \emptyset, [n]\rbrace$. It will be convenient to use the notation $A^{-}$ for $A^c$ and define $A^{+}=A$ ; then $A^{\pm}$ means "$A$ or its complement". Say also that $A,B \subseteq [n]$ are independent if all four intersections $A^{\pm}\cap B^{\pm}$ are nonempty.

**Step 1.** $\cal F$ does not contain three mutually independent subsets.

Suppose that $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are mutually independent subsets in $\cal F$. Let $s_1$ and $s_2$ be signs in $\pm$. By independence, $A_1^{s_1}\cap A_2^{s_2}$ is nonempty, so at least one of $A_1^{s_1}\cap A_2^{s_2}\cap A_3^{-}$ and $A_1^{s_1}\cap A_2^{s_2}\cap A_3^{+}$ is non-empty. When $(s_1,s_2)$ varies over its four possible values, this already gives us four non-empty triple intersections, which contradicts the hypothesis on $\cal F$. QED

**Step 2.**  ${\cal F}'$ does not contain an increasing sequence of three subsets.

Indeed, if $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3$ is an increasing sequence of three subsets in $\cal E$, then the following four intersections are nonempty : $A_1^{-}\cap A_2^{-}\cap A_3^{-}$, $A_1^{-}\cap A_2^{-}\cap A_3^{+}$, $A_1^{-}\cap A_2^{+}\cap A_3^{+}$, $A_1^{+}\cap A_2^{+}\cap A_3^{+}$. QED

**Step 3.**  ${\cal F}'$ does not contain four mutually disjoint subsets, or four subsets whose complements are mutually disjoint.

Indeed, if $A_k(1\leq k\leq 4)$ are four mutually disjoint subsets in $\cal E$, then the following four intersections are nonempty : $A_1^{+}\cap A_2^{-}\cap A_3^{-}$, $A_1^{-}\cap A_2^{+}\cap A_3^{-}$, $A_1^{+}\cap A_2^{-}\cap A_3^{-}$, $A_1^{-}\cap A_2^{-}\cap A_3^{-}$. QED

**Step 4.** $|{\cal F}'| \lt R(2,R(4,4,3))$.

Suppose by contradiction that $|{\cal F}'| \geq R(2,R(4,4,3))$. Then, by step 1, there is a ${\cal F}'' \subseteq {\cal F}'$ or cardinality at least $R(4,4,3)$ such that any $A,B \in {\cal F}''$ are never independent ; so there must be signs $s_A,s_B$  such that $A^{s_A}\cap B^{s_B}=\emptyset$. Color a pair $(A,B)$ blue if $(s_A,s_B)=(-,-)$, red if $(s_A,s_B)=(+,+)$, and yellow otherwise. Then, we must have either a blue or red four-set (ruled out by step 3), or a yellow three-set (ruled out by step 2). This finishes the proof.

Comment: In step 1, do you mean $\cal F'$?  Perhaps I misunderstand the term "mutual independence" when it comes to sets -- but when it comes to probability the events $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are considered mutually independent with everything else.

Comment: @antkam 1) No, step 1 happens to be the only step where you can work on $\cal F$ directly rather than ${\cal F}'$. 2) Indeed, "independence" here has a meaning different from the probabilistic one.